# Getting a 404 on gh-pages for new organisation

Tags: github-pages

Anyone with a keen eye see what I’ve done wrong?:

https://github.com/quantumjs/quantumjs.github.io

http://quantumjs.github.io/

There isn't a GitHub Pages site here.

Comment: Strange. Did you check your repository settings > Github pages for publication branch ? If you've left default settings, it can be a Github pages bug. Send them a message.

Comment: i contacted github thx

Comment: If you've solved this, you should post the answer here to help others.

Answer (score 1):

So what happened was I had changed the name of the repo, and had to ask github support to rebuild the site, which got it to work.